# twitter oauth api with wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I have a WP multisite installation with various users each having their own installation

Ie

www.mysite.com/fearghal

www.mysite.com/john

etc.

Is there a way I can use one Twitter application that will allow each user to update their status? I know with one site it is simple, but with multiple url's like WP MS - could be tricky with various callback urls.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. When you get a request token you will have to pass the callback url for that site to Twitter and callback URL will have a verifier passed to it that will need to be sent when you get an access token. You can read more about the process at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth